# Pygame 'module' object has no attribute 'event'

Tags: pygame

I'm using pygame to make program wait for a mouse click. My code is this:

```
import pygame
import pyautogui

done = True
while done:
    event = pygame.event.wait()
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrlleft")
        done = True
```

But I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/WantedStarling/Desktop/pygame.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:/Users/WantedStarling/Desktop\pygame.py", line 5, in <module>
    event = pygame.event.wait()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'event'`enter code here`
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not name your game `pygame.py`, otherwise Python will think that your game module is the actual pygame module, and because your game doesn't have an `event` attribute, it will raise the `AttributeError`.

Rename your module to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `pygame.init()` before using any of its functions. Calling this anywhere before your loop should solve the problem.

FYI you can import multiple modules in one line.

```
import pygame, pyautogui
pygame.init()
```

Comment: Now I get this error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'

Comment: It's correct that you need to call `pygame.init()`, but that's not the cause of the problem. Also, it's recommended that you put the imports in separate lines (see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)).